# How do you work out the position of a rotated line?

Tags: rotations

If I have a line segment that starts at origins and is parallel to the x-axis, how do I work out the position on the X axis of x if it is rotated by say 45 degrees?

I know the degree and I know the length of the line.. so I use what formula?

Is it cos(angle) / length?

Comment: Draw a picture -- it's a right triangle. Then you're pretty much done.

Comment: could you explain that.. I need a way to write is in a formula?

Comment: the hypotenuse is your line segment's length and the angle it makes with the $x$-axis is your angle. The answer will turn out to be $({\rm length})\cdot\cos({\rm angle})$.

Comment: so what was that stuff on the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29#Matrix_algebra ... Like it semaed to say "the new position of x = cos(angle) - sin(angle) * length"

Comment: I'm not sure where you're finding the thing you're referring to. In your case, you are looking for $x'$ while $x={\rm length}$ and $y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29

This article provides the complete detail of your requisite

Comment: yes i found that but i do not understand it. I need to find the location of x, after rotation?

Comment: like is it saying... "the new position of x = cos(angle) - sin(angle) * length" ?